# How to use React hooks + Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

---

### Is this the best way to connect Redux store with hooks?

Hi I am making a simple todo app using React hooks connected to Redux. The pattern I created works but I wonder if I'm doing it right, is there something wrong with this approach, is there a different pattern one should use?

```js
App.jsx

  const [initialTodos, updateTodos] = useState(store.getState());

  const cleanup = store.subscribe(() => updateTodos(store.getState()));

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => cleanup();
  });
```

> dispatching happens in other components + the todo app works

Thank you for any input

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It turns out it is better too use 'react-redux' `connect`.

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({state: state})

connect(mapStateToProps)(Component)
```

since connect automagically takes care of store.subscribe etc.

So drop hooks all together :)

Comment: This is out of date. `connect()` isn't needed anymore. Please check my answer for current implementation.

Comment: when hooks come up to make our code much more easily so why we have to use the old ways? As @Hugodby commented before, using `useSelector ` and `useDispatch ` is easier.

Answer (score 0):

`react-redux` package supports hooks since v7.1. Redux hooks can be used instead of the `connect()` function.

This is an example implementing a counter where the counter value is managed by Redux.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const CounterComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{counter}</span>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT_COUNTER' })}>
        Increment counter
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Source: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks