# Using redux with react hooks

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I'm trying to figure out the best way to use redux with react hooks.  I saw the following

[How to use React hooks + Redux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54880976/how-to-use-react-hooks-redux)

However I'm not convinced this is the best way to go.  Does anyone have any alternative ideas?

I also saw the following and seems quite good.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-react-hook

Thanks

Comment: react-redux v7.x will get an official hook for redux https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/releases/tag/v7.0.0-beta.0?utm_campaign=React%2BNewsletter&utm_medium=web&utm_source=React_Newsletter_154

Comment: `redux-react-hook` is a good package... you can read the entire source in a few minutes

Comment: I've also developed an abstraction over redux that uses hooks. https://github.com/ctrlplusb/easy-peasy

Comment: After doing this recently myself I posted this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56231851/how-to-connect-redux-store-using-useselector-when-input-fields-already-mapped/56254951#56254951 Make sure you npm I react-redux@next Cheers

Answer (score 2):

The official `react-redux` package provides hooks since v7.1. Redux hooks can be used instead of the `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)` function.

#### `useSelector()`

Extract data from the Redux store state using a selector function.

#### `useDispatch()`

Return a reference to dispatch that can be used to dispatch actions.

This is an example implementing a counter where the counter value is managed by Redux.

```js
import React from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'

export const CounterComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const counter = useSelector(state => state.counter);

  return (
    <div>
      <span>{counter}</span>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: 'INCREMENT_COUNTER' })}>
        Increment counter
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Source: https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to redux you can use hooks to manage the state, you can create the similar using the combination of [context api](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) and custom hooks

```js
const initialState = {
    stateSet: false,
    plan: {
    }
}
const AppReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    return {
        plan: planReducer(state.plan, action)
    }
}



const AppProvider = (props) => {

    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);
    return (
        <AppStateContext.Provider value={state}>
            <AppDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
                {props.children}

            </AppDispatchContext.Provider>
        </AppStateContext.Provider>
    )


}

const useAppState = () => {
    const context = React.useContext(AppStateContext);
    return context;
}


const useAppDispatch = () => {
    const context = React.useContext(AppDispatchContext);
    return context;
}
```

then inside your component, you can any component

```
const { plan } = useAppState();
 dispatch({ type: 'updateBusinessInfo', payload: { businessInfo: businessInfo, addOnsInfo: addOnsInfo } });
```

refer https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively fantastic post by kencdoods for details

Answer (score 0):

At the time of writing this is still in alpha stage, if you want to try it update your react-redux to v7.1.0-alpha.4.

https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#hooks

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how to use Redux with Hooks in 3 simple steps : Counter example.**

**Source code: https://github.com/trackmystories/Redux-hooks-counter-app-with-axios.**

NOTE: *https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started*

**Step 1:**

create a reducer.js file, define and combine your reducers:

*reducer.js*

```html
    import { combineReducers } from "redux";

 
    const counter = (state = 0, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD":
          return state + 1;
        case "SUBTRACT":
          return state - 1;
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
    
  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    counter
    // additional reducers ...
});

export default rootReducer;
```

**Step 2**

Create a counter component which will access the state and render it to the view:

NOTE: *please refer to "Redux Terms and Concepts" to get a better understanding of Actions, State and View.
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts*

You don't need to use connect mapStateToProps and dispatchStateToProps with redux hooks instead use { useDispatch, useSelector }.

We can pass the actions "ADD" and "SUBTRACT" inside of the button directly, without defining an action.js file.

*CounterComponent.js*

```html
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

export default function CounterComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch(); // dispatct action "ADD","SUBTRACT".
  const counter = useSelector((state) => state.counter); // your apps state.
  
    return (
    <div>
     // dispatch "SUBTRACT"
     <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "SUBTRACT",})}>
         SUBTRACT
      <button>

        // pass the current state 
        <text> display count : {counter}</text> 


       // dispatch "ADD"
       <button onClick={() => dispatch({ type: "ADD",})}>
          ADD
       <button>

      </div>
     )
     
    }
```

**Step 3:**

Lastly link your RootReducer to the createStore and pass it to the Provider.

*App.js*

```html
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore } from "redux";

import CounterComponent from './CounterComponent.jsx';


 
// import your reducers
import rootReducer from "./reducers"; 


// link your reducers to the store 
const store = createStore(rootReducer); 



// Pass your store to the Provider wrapping your Component. 

export default function App() {
  return (
     <>
      <Provider store={store}> 
        <CounterComponent/>
      </Provider>
    </>
  );
};
```